# JavaScript Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

This quick code I made is meant to be an easy-to-use, multi-purpose calculator. When I say "multi-purpose", then I mean that this calculator can do some more interesting functions like rounding numbers to the nearest one (which isn't that interesting, honestly). I was hoping to get some feedback or review on how my coding structure and methods could be improved.

[Here](https://codehs.com/share/FWcr6RPJt8k9kUjarvAI) is the code "in action".

```
function start(){
var type = readLine("What type of calculation would you like to do?");

if(type == "multiplication"){
    var mFirstNum = readInt("What is the first number you want to multiply?");
    var mSecondNum = readInt("What is the second number you want to multiply?");
    var product = (mFirstNum * mSecondNum);
    println("The product is " + product);

}else if(type == "addition"){
    var aFirstNum = readInt("What is the first number you want to add?");
    var aSecondNum = readInt("What is the second number you want to add?");
    var sum = (aFirstNum + aSecondNum);
    println("The sum is " + sum);

}else if(type == "subtraction"){
    var sFirstNum = readInt("What is the first number you want to subtract?");
    var sSecondNum = readInt("What is the second number you want to subtract?");
    var difference = (sFirstNum - sSecondNum);
    println("The difference is " + difference);

}else if(type == "division"){
    var dFirstNum = readInt("What is the first number you want to divide?");
    var dSecondNum = readInt("What is the second number you want to divide?");
    var quotient = (dFirstNum / dSecondNum);
    println("The quotient is " + quotient);

}else if(type == "square root"){
    var sqFirstNum = readInt("What is the number you would like to find the square root of?");
    var sqRoot = Math.sqrt(sqFirstNum);
    println(sqRoot);

}else if(type == "round"){
    var roundFirstNum = readFloat("What is the decimal you want to round?");
    var roundedNum = Math.round(roundFirstNum);
    println(roundedNum);

}else if(type == "max number"){
    var numO = readInt("What is the first number you want to compare?");
    var numT = readInt("What is the second number you want to compare?");

    var final = max(numO, numT);
    println("The bigger number is " + final);

}else if(type == null){
    println("Goodbye.");

}else{
    println("That is not a valid calculation.");
}
}
function max(x, y){
    if(x > y){
        max = x;
    }else{
        max = y;
    }
    return max;
}
```